# Sphinx search not giving id and text field information

Tags: sphinx

I am very new to sphinx and I have a small question. I have sphinx.conf file as follows

```
sql_query       = \
    SELECT id, user_id, title \
    FROM table

sql_attr_uint       = user_id
sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id
```

I have a php file that utilizes sphinxapi.php and contains the following code

```
  // connect to mysql database //
    require_once('sphinxapi.php');
    $s = new SphinxClient;
    $s->setServer("127.0.0.1", 9312);
    $s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
    $s->SetLimits(0, 2);
    $result = $s->Query('test words');
```

If I print $result it has user_id fields but doesn't contain id or title fields. Is there a way to retrieve those too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will have the id. Its jsut not in the 'attrs' array, its the key of the 'matches' array.

The 'text' of fields is not stored, so sphinx can't return it. To get the title, go back to your original database. It will be a very quick query as it can just use the list of ids in a IN(..) query.

(although you can opt to put the text in a string attribute, which sphinx will then store and return in the attrs array. Can use sql_field_string, to make a column, BOTH a field and an attribute)

Comment: I tried to add title as a string attribute, but it doesn't let me. Throws "no fields in schema - will not index" error ... also i checked if ids are the keys for matches array and it's not... the key are just numbers starting from 1 and then 2,3 and so on

Comment: You cant make it JUST an attribute. You need some fields to index. Fields are what power searching. You can make a column BOTH however.

Comment: If you got numbers 1, 2 and 3, then you got documents 1, 2 and 3. Those are IDs! If they where sequential indexes, would start from 0 and would require use of SetArrayResult

Comment: okay my bad about the index thingy :), I had forgotten to reindex ... but i still can't get attributes to work... one quick question though, are there any drawbacks in storing text fields in string attribute?

Comment: The benefit/drawback, is attributes are held in memory. So the amount of memory avialable is a limit, you need enough server memory to store all attributes. But cos they stored in memory its good for performance. All by default all attributes are returned in results, in the results, so be careful about adding lots of attributes, and not using them, thereby wasting bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sql_query       = \
    SELECT id, user_id, title, title as title_str \
    FROM table

sql_field_string = title_str
```